# Disable Datepicker on click of inactive textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, bootstrap-datepicker

How can I disable datepicker on click of textbox which is inactive ? I have used the following attributes readonly, disabled which doesn’t help.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

My code:

```
$("[id$=_txtTDate]").datepicker();
<td width="225px">
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtTDate" runat="server" MaxLength="10" Text='<%#Eval("TDate").ToShortDateString() %>' ToolTip='<%#Eval("TDate").ToShortDateString() %>' Width="150" CssClass="datepicker form-control form-control-inline" ReadOnly="true" />
</td>
```

Comment: Show some code please... Your HTML and the JS for datepicker. Also, is it jQuery datepicker or BootStrap datepicker? The more relevant infos you give, the most accurate answer you will get.

Comment: $("[id$=_txtTDate]").datepicker();

 <td width="225px"><asp:TextBox ID="txtTDate" runat="server" MaxLength="10" Text='<%#Eval("TDate").ToShortDateString() %>' ToolTip='<%#Eval("TDate").ToShortDateString() %>' Width="150" CssClass="datepicker form-control form-control-inline" ReadOnly="true"   /></td>

Comment: Please use the "edit" link below your question next time. I've done it for you. See? You are using ASP... This is an important info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery's off() method to disable any event on a specific element. Also you could use not() method to skip any certain event for a specific element.

For example elements like below,

```
First: <input type="text" name="f" value="1"><br>
Second: <input type="text" name="s" class="myclass" value="2"> <br>

Third: <input type="text" name="t" disabled value="3"> <br>
```

using the following code will prevent clicking second and third element.

```
// Use not as [all except]
$("input:not(.myclass)").on("click", function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});

// Or Use off()
$("input:disabled").off(event);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nuhil/8typL6c5/